# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Spring MVC project fails to start because of Unsatisfied Dependency

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, annotations

I am trying to start a spring mvc application,
and keep receiving the following error which I cannot solve

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
```

And this is only the first error shown in the console.
Well, I am trying to understand the first part of the whole line, which is
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field `customerDAO` Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field `customerDAO`. It is giving a 500 server error. I cannot find any similar solution, neither see where the error is. Here are my source code files so far:
the entity class

```java
package com.wcorp.springdemo.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    
    public Customer() {
        
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }
        
}
```

the dao Interface and its implementation

```java
import com.wcorp.springdemo.entity.Customer;

public interface CustomerDAO {

    public List<Customer> getCustomers();
    
}
```

```java
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.wcorp.springdemo.entity.Customer;

@Repository
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {

    // need to inject the session factory
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
            
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        
        // get the current hibernate session
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
                
        // create a query
        Query<Customer> theQuery = 
                currentSession.createQuery("from Customer", Customer.class);
        
        // execute query and get result list
        List<Customer> customers = theQuery.getResultList();
                
        // return the results       
        return customers;
    }

}
```

The controller

```java
package com.wcorp.springdemo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.wcorp.springdemo.dao.CustomerDAO;
import com.wcorp.springdemo.entity.Customer;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    // need to inject the customer dao
    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomers(Model theModel) {

        // get customers from the dao
        List<Customer> theCustomers = customerDAO.getCustomers();

        // add the customers to the model
        theModel.addAttribute("customers", theCustomers);

        return "list-customers";
    }

}
```

Here is the spring config file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.wcorp.springdemo" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
        <property name="user" value="springstudent2" />
        <property name="password" value="springstudent2" /> 

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>  
    
    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.wcorp.springdemo.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>    

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

</beans>
```

the project build path, jars and tomcat server is fine eclipse is not complaining, spring version is 5.0.2, hibernate version 5.2.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar problem described [here](http://qaru.site/questions/17558795/could-not-get-constructor-for-orghibernatepersisterentitysingletableentitypersister-nullpointerexception)

Please try to run under `Java 8`. The problem comes that you use `Java 11`.

Most of the frameworks are not compatible and are not fully tested on Java 11.